# Wordpress: Limit number of tags added to post

Tags: wordpress

in this code;

```
if (!is_array($keywords)) {
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
}
foreach ($keywords as $thetag) {
wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);
}
```

How can i limit the number of tags added to the post?

Will this work

```
if (!is_array($keywords)) {
$count=0;
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
}
foreach ($keywords as $thetag) {
$count++;
wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);
if( $count > 3 ) break;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps $count=0; if( $count >4 ) break; something like this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it worked!!!!!

```
if (!is_array($keywords)) {
$count=0;
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
}
foreach ($keywords as $thetag) {
$count++;
wp_add_post_tags($post_id, $thetag);
if( $count > 3 ) break;
}
```

Comment: But how do i only fetch the tags which character lenght is higher than 2